# Passing class props to mapStateToProps

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a component connected to the store, one of the props being passed in to the component is a `post` which is an object. I want to pass the `post.id` to `mapStateToProps` so that I can watch for changes to the posts comments array.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  myProfile: state.users.myProfile,
  comments: state.activity.posts[this.postID].comments,
});

const mapStateToProps2 = state => {
  const id = this.postID;

  return {
    myProfile: state.users.myProfile,
    comments: state.activity.posts[id].comments,
  };
};
```

anyone know if I can do this, any ideas how?

cheers

**EDIT**
Here is the implementation I went with in the end:

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => { 
    const { navigation } = ownProps; 
    const navPost = navigation.getParam('post', {}); 

    const postComments = state.activity.posts.filter( post => post.id === navPost.id );

    return { 
       myProfile: state.users.myProfile, 
       comments: postComments[0].comments, 
    }; 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword is most likely referencing the wrong scope and can't find `postId`.

Either assign the ID in the state and access it like `state.postId` or pass the id to the component's properties and use that like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const { visibilityFilter } = state
  const { id } = ownProps
  const todo = getTodoById(state, id)

  // component receives additionally:
  return { todo, visibilityFilter }
}

// Later, in your application, a parent component renders:
;<ConnectedTodo id={123} />
// and your component receives props.id, props.todo, and props.visibilityFilter
```

Source: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Comment: you sir, are a superstar.

for anyone looking for my final implementation
`const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { navigation } = ownProps;
  const navPost = navigation.getParam('post', {});
  const postComments = state.activity.posts.filter(
    post => post.id === navPost.id
  );
  return {
    myProfile: state.users.myProfile,
    comments: postComments[0].comments,
  };
};`

Comment: @virtualLast Thank you! Do you mind adding your solution as an edit in your question so it gets formatted correctly to make it easier to read for future visitors?